# How do I find the ordering that sorts a list in Haskell?

Tags: list, sorting, haskell

In Haskell, how do I find the ordering that sorts a given list — that is, the indices to apply to the list that would result in its being sorted?

Essentially what I'm looking for is the Haskell equivalent of [*Mathematica's* `Ordering`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
ordering :: Ord a => [a] -> [Int]
ordering xs = map snd $ sort (zip xs [0..])
```